# create Collision With Blocks and Player

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection

hii guys i am trying do Collision with the player

and the blocks like these examples:
[image]

that is collision with the ground that work perfect the player when though the ground is stop to jump

[image]

that is collision with roof that he cant continue to jump after tough the blocks
so he continue to fall (work perfect)

my problem now is the left collision and right

like that
[image]

i will happy if someone can help me with that
to make him not posible to continue move right after tough the block

this is my classes
my right and left not working

**UpdateCollision.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;


class UpdateCollision
{
    public Player myPlayer;
    public Map myMap;

    public Block toughtBlock;

    public void Initialize(Player myPlayer, Map myMap)
    {
        this.myPlayer = myPlayer;
        this.myMap = myMap;
    }

    public bool IsPlayerToughGround()
    {

        Rectangle Player;
        Rectangle BlockDown;

        // Only create the rectangle once for the player
        Player = new Rectangle((int)myPlayer.Position.X,
        (int)myPlayer.Position.Y,
        myPlayer.Width/2,
        myPlayer.Height/2);

        // Do the collision between the player and the Block

        int i, j;

        bool isTough = false;

        // For each block in the game
        for (i = 0; i < (myMap.Height / myMap.pictureSize) && !isTough; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < (myMap.Width / myMap.pictureSize) && !isTough; j++)
            {
                // If the block is Draw
                if (myMap.Blocks[i, j].isAlive)
                {


                    BlockDown = new Rectangle((int)myMap.Blocks[i, j].X,
                                              (int)myMap.Blocks[i, j].Y,
                                               myMap.pictureSize,
                                               myMap.pictureSize);


                    // Determine if the two objects collided with each
                    // other
                    if (Player.Intersects(BlockDown)) 
                    {
                        isTough = true;
                        toughtBlock = myMap.Blocks[i, j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return isTough;


    }

    public bool IsPlayerToughRoof()
    {

        Rectangle Player;
        Rectangle Blockup;

        // Only create the rectangle once for the player
        Player = new Rectangle((int)myPlayer.Position.X,
        (int)myPlayer.Position.Y,
        myPlayer.Width / 2,
        myPlayer.Height / 2);

        // Do the collision between the player and the Block

        int i, j;

        bool isTough = false;

        // For each block in the game
        for (i = 0; i < (myMap.Height / myMap.pictureSize) && !isTough; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < (myMap.Width / myMap.pictureSize) && !isTough; j++)
            {
                // If the block is Draw
                if (myMap.Blocks[i, j].isAlive)
                {
                    Blockup = new Rectangle((int)myMap.Blocks[i, j].X,
                                            (int)myMap.Blocks[i, j].Y + 20,
                                                 myMap.pictureSize,
                                                 myMap.pictureSize);


                    // Determine if the two objects collided with each
                    // other
                    if (Player.Intersects(Blockup))
                    {
                        isTough = true;
                        toughtBlock = myMap.Blocks[i, j];
                    }


                }
            }
        }

        return isTough;
    }

    public bool IsPlayerToughLeft()
    {

        Rectangle Player;
        Rectangle BlockLeft;

        // Only create the rectangle once for the player
        Player = new Rectangle((int)myPlayer.Position.X,
        (int)myPlayer.Position.Y,
        myPlayer.Width ,
        myPlayer.Height );

        // Do the collision between the player and the Block

        int i, j;

        bool isTough = false;

        // For each block in the game
        for (i = 0; i < myMap.Height / myMap.pictureSize; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < myMap.Width / myMap.pictureSize; j++)
            {
                // If the block is Draw
                if (myMap.Blocks[i, j].isAlive)
                {

                    BlockLeft = new Rectangle((int)myMap.Blocks[i, j].X +20,
                                          (int)myMap.Blocks[i, j].Y,
                                               myMap.pictureSize,
                                               myMap.pictureSize);



                    // Determine if the two objects collided with each
                    // other
                    if (Player.Intersects(BlockLeft))
                        {
                            isTough = true;
                            toughtBlock = myMap.Blocks[i, j];
                        }


                }
            }
        }

        return isTough;
    }

    public bool IsPlayerToughRight()
    {

        Rectangle Player;
        Rectangle Blockup;
        Rectangle BlockDown;
        Rectangle BlockLeft;
        Rectangle BlockRight;

        // Only create the rectangle once for the player
        Player = new Rectangle((int)myPlayer.Position.X,
        (int)myPlayer.Position.Y,
        myPlayer.Width / 2,
        myPlayer.Height / 2);

        // Do the collision between the player and the Block

        int i, j;

        bool isTough = false;

        // For each block in the game
        for (i = 0; i < (myMap.Height / myMap.pictureSize) && !isTough; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < (myMap.Width / myMap.pictureSize) && !isTough; j++)
            {
                // If the block is Draw
                if (myMap.Blocks[i, j].isAlive)
                {
                    Blockup = new Rectangle((int)myMap.Blocks[i, j].X,
                                          (int)myMap.Blocks[i, j].Y + 20,
                                               myMap.pictureSize,
                                               myMap.pictureSize);

                    BlockDown = new Rectangle((int)myMap.Blocks[i, j].X,
                                          (int)myMap.Blocks[i, j].Y,
                                               myMap.pictureSize,
                                               myMap.pictureSize);

                    BlockLeft = new Rectangle((int)myMap.Blocks[i, j].X + 20,
                                          (int)myMap.Blocks[i, j].Y,
                                               myMap.pictureSize,
                                               myMap.pictureSize);



                    // Determine if the two objects collided with each
                    // other
                    if (Player.Intersects(Blockup) ||
                        Player.Intersects(BlockDown) ||
                        Player.Intersects(BlockLeft))// ||
                    //Player.Intersects(BlockRight))
                    {
                        isTough = true;
                        toughtBlock = myMap.Blocks[i, j];
                    }


                }
            }
        }

        return isTough;
    }
}
```

using them in the KeyBoardHeadler

**KeyBoardHeadler.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;

    class KeyBoardHeadler
    {
        KeyboardState myKeyBoard;

        // A movement speed for the player
        float playerMoveSpeed;

        float Gravity;

        float JumpSpeed;

        // The graphic device
        GraphicsDevice gamedevice;

        // The Contect that load texture
        ContentManager LoadTexture;

        // The vector that move the gravity
        Vector2 velocity;

        UpdateCollision Coll;

        Player player;
        Map map;


        bool RightIsOk=true;
        bool LeftIsOk=true;

        public void Initialize(GraphicsDevice gv, ContentManager mainTexture, Player player, Map map)
        {


            // Get keyboard statement
            myKeyBoard = new KeyboardState();

            // Set a constant player move speed
            playerMoveSpeed = 3.0f;

            // Set Gravity vector
            velocity = Vector2.Zero;

            // Gravity amount
            Gravity = 10f;

            // Jump Speed
            JumpSpeed = 400f;

            // Get the graphic device
            gamedevice = gv;

            // Get Contect Manger to change player texture
            LoadTexture = mainTexture;

            // Initlize collision
            Coll = new UpdateCollision();
            Coll.Initialize(player, map);

            // Initalize map and player
            this.player = player;
            this.map = map;

        }

        public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {


            // Read the current state of the keyboard and gamepad and store it
            myKeyBoard = Keyboard.GetState();

            // Use the Keyboard / Dpad
            if (myKeyBoard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) && LeftIsOk)
            {
                player.PlayerAnimation.elapsedTime +=(int)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
                player.PlayerAnimation.spriteStrip = LoadTexture.Load<Texture2D>("Player\\Left");
                player.PlayerAnimation.frameCount = 2;
                player.Position.X -= playerMoveSpeed;

            }
            if (myKeyBoard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) && RightIsOk)
            {
                player.PlayerAnimation.elapsedTime += (int)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
                player.PlayerAnimation.spriteStrip = LoadTexture.Load<Texture2D>("Player\\Right");
                player.PlayerAnimation.frameCount = 2;
                player.Position.X += playerMoveSpeed;
            }
            if (myKeyBoard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up) && !player.isJump)
            {
                // add the gravity to the Player
                velocity.Y = -JumpSpeed * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
                player.isJump = true;
            }

            if (player.isJump)
                velocity.Y += Gravity * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
            else
                velocity.Y = 0;


            // Add the position of the jump
            player.Position.Y += velocity.Y;

            // If the Player tough anything
            if (Coll.IsPlayerToughGround())
            {
                // if the Player is not jump
                if (Coll.myPlayer.Position.Y <= Coll.toughtBlock.Y)
                {
                    player.isJump = false;
                    velocity.Y = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                player.isJump = true;
            }

            if (Coll.IsPlayerToughRoof())
            {
                velocity.Y = 2;
            }

            if (Coll.IsPlayerToughLeft())
            {
                int x=6;
            }

            // Make sure that the player does not go out of bounds (get the area of the game (between 0 - max of map)
            player.Position.X = MathHelper.Clamp(player.Position.X, 0, gamedevice.Viewport.Width - player.Width + 25);
            player.Position.Y = MathHelper.Clamp(player.Position.Y, 0, gamedevice.Viewport.Height - player.Height + 50);

            if (myKeyBoard.IsKeyDown(Keys.NumPad0))
            {
                player.Position = new Vector2(100, 100);
                velocity.Y = 0;

            }
            if (myKeyBoard.IsKeyDown(Keys.NumPad1))
            {
                player.isJump = !player.isJump;

            }

        }

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {

        }

    }
```

is there any option to  check only tought on the X axis

Comment: I'm also trying solve this task, but my solution is not complete yet. But I recommend you Fast Voxel Traversal Algorithm for Ray Tracing. There are no need to create rectangles for each grid to check collision so it much faster. Maybe later i'm post answer with code snippet.

Comment: ty i will wait for you SOlution i really try solve that

Comment: A few hours later I put my solution on bitbucket. He is lame, but in general it works. I also just learning and I would like to see the response from the more experienced developer.

Comment: See my solution heare https://bitbucket.org/prostokiriuha/platformer. It's required GameHelper lib, you can find it in WindRock project.